# Python: AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'send_Keys'

Tags: python, selenium, warnings

I try to code a web automation with Selenium but I always get the error message:

> textArea.send_Keys(username) AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has
>   no attribute 'send_Keys'

Can anybody help me??
And I know that I haven't finished the code, I could shorten text out, but I just want it to work for now.

Here is the code:

```
def commentAndLike():
random.seed()
likeOrNext = random.randint(0, 3)

if likeOrNext == 0:
    if check_exists_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button/span"):
        likeButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button/span")
        likeButton.click()

        time.sleep(randomNumber(6, 10))

        if check_exists_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[1]/span[2]/button/span"):
            random.seed()
            randomComment = random.randint(0, 3)

            commenButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[1]/span[2]/button/span")
            commenButton.click()

            time.sleep(randomNumber(2, 4))

            textArea = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[3]/div[1]/form/textarea")

            time.sleep(randomNumber(2, 4))

            if randomComment == 0:
                textArea.send_keys(username)
            elif randomComment == 1:
                textArea.send_Keys(username)
            elif randomComment == 2:
                textArea.send_Keys(username)
            elif randomComment == 3:
                textArea.send_Keys(username)

            time.sleep(randomNumber(15, 30))

            postButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[3]/div/form/button")
            postButton.click()

            time.sleep(randomNumber(20, 25))

            nextButton2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/a[2]")
            nextButton2.click()

            time.sleep(randomNumber(15, 20))

        else:
            nextButton4 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/a[2]")
            nextButton4.click()

            time.sleep(randomNumber(20, 25))

    else:
        nextButton1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/a[2]")
        nextButton1.click()

        time.sleep(randomNumber(20, 25))

else:
    nextButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/a[2]")
    nextButton.click()

    time.sleep(randomNumber(20,25))
```

Answer (score 1):

`send_Keys` is wrong syntax, the K should be lowercase: `send_keys`.

Some docs to help with other syntax: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html